# How to avoid authentications on SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I deployed an SSRS report on my PC and am able to access my report through Report Manager.

When I copy that report URL and open the report URL in another PC through network, the report asks for credential.

When I give my Windows credentials on the second PC it works.

How can I avoid providing credentials (my user name and password) to open a report?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the authentication settings in the IIS configuration. You need to log on to the server, open the IIS management console, right click the Reporting Service entries below the "Default Web Site" (not using English Windows, so it may be named differently) and change the security settings to include Windows Authentication.

Comment: SSRS 2008 and above do not run on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

If your report is not asking for credentials locally but it is from other locations, it's most likely a web browser setting that's affecting this.

For Internet Explorer, you need to make sure **User Authentication** is set correctly in **Internet Options** -> **Security Settings**:

[image]

Note that here it's set to **Automatic logon with current user name and password**.

When set like this for the appropriate zone you should not be prompted for credentials.

There are also wider security considerations here, as it will apply to all websites visited in a particular zone.

See also: [Enter Credentials](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/878c6a48-892b-4c98-b0b4-3de55ab4f83a).

Comment: Hi Ian,I changed what u explained above but its not worked.My problem is When I sent MY Report Manager URL another Pc by that time asked credentials for username and password MY PC,Here When i give its working fine. Can u tell me any solution, Urgent requiement